# Please help me with 2d system graph in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, systeme

Please help me with 2 system i want to generate the two graphs with systems

First

{  =  ∙ ( ∙ ) + 0

{  =  ∙ ( ∙ ) + 0

Second

{  = () ∙ sin () + 0

{  = ()sin () + 0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: i cant generate the graphic with system

Comment: How do the two linked questions not work for you?  What do you mean by "can't generate the graphic"?

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={->},
tick style={color=black},
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty
]

\addplot[samples=360, domain=0:2*pi] 
({x = a * sin(b*t)+x_0}, {x= a * sin(d*t)+y_0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: ({x = a * sin(b*t)+x_0}, {y= a * sin(d*t)+y_0})