# Help me generate graph with system

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, systeme

Please help me with system I want to generate the graphs with system

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={->},
tick style={color=black},
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty
]

\addplot[samples=360, domain=0:2*pi] 
({x = a * sin(b * t) + x_0}, {y = a * sin(d * t) + y_0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This system

{  =  ∙ ( ∙ ) + 0

{  =  ∙ ( ∙ ) + 0

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: And what is x0 and y0?

Comment: In this forum, you should know a bit about how to ask a question (with MWE), how to accept an answer, etc

Comment: [Your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631968/please-help-me-with-2d-system-graph-in-latex), which was the same, was closed as duplicate and you come back and ask the same thing without learning how to ask questions properly. Yous posted four times now and three of your posts have been closed. Maybe it's time to learn how to behave on TeX-SE.

Answer (score 3):

Lissajous functions. Two examples plotted:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        
        % axex and grid
        \draw[gray!15] (-3.6,-3.6) grid [step=0.5] (3.6,3.6);
        \draw[-latex] (-3.6,0) -- (3.6,0) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-3.6) -- (0,3.6) node [above] {$y$};
        \foreach \i in {-3.5,-3.0,...,-.5,0.5,1,1.5,...,3.5}
        \draw (\i,0.05) -- (\i,-0.05) node [below] {\tiny $\i$};
        \foreach\i in {-3.5,-3.0,...,-.5,0.5,1,1.5,...,3.5}
        \draw (0.05,\i) -- (-0.05,\i) node [left]  {\tiny $\i$};
        
        % function1 to draw
        \draw[cyan, very thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=-30*pi:30*pi,smooth] ({3 * sin(7 * \t)}, {2 * sin(5 * \t)});
    
        % function2 to draw
        \draw[red, very thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=-60*pi:60*pi,smooth] ({2 * sin(2 * \t)}, {3 * sin(3 * \t)});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

OUTCOME:

[image]

ADD:
From Lorenzo Pantieri manual, with this code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [title={Figura di Lissajous}]
            \addplot
            [domain=0:360,variable=\t,
            samples=200,smooth,thick,blue]
            ({sin(7*t)},{sin(2*t)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{document}
```

you have the following output:

[image]

Comment: Definitely needs to increase the number of samples to make those curves smoother and more accurate, but nice answer.

Comment: i want to draw with \addplot

Comment: @ Nika I have added added what you search: the graph with addplot (from a document of Lorenzo Pantieri).